# EventHandler OPC UA

Tags: events, notifications, opc-ua

i'm trying to communicate a server to a client using opc ua, it works fine until the point I want my program to return values. Im using a OnNotification function:

```
public void OnNotification(MonitoredItem item, MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e)
{
   // Debug.Log("Entre aqui");

    foreach (var value in item.DequeueValues())
    {
       // Debug.Log("Entre aqui otra vez");
        //Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}", item.DisplayName, value.Value, value.SourceTimestamp, value.StatusCode);
        Debug.Log("{0}: {1}, {2}, {3}" + item.DisplayName + value.Value + value.SourceTimestamp + value.StatusCode);
        //rotZ = float.Parse(value.Value.ToString());
        //J1.Rotate(0, 0, rotZ);
    }
}
```

This is where I create the Monitored Item and I add the MonitoredItem EventHandler to the function, but I don't why the event of i.Notification never occurs, so it never runs the OnNotification function.
Should I trigger the event to occur? What am I doing wrong?

```
        var filter = new EventFilter();


        var triggeringItemId = new MonitoredItem(subscription.DefaultItem)
        {
            NodeClass = NodeClass.Object,
            StartNodeId = ObjectIds.Server,
            AttributeId = Attributes.EventNotifier,
            MonitoringMode = MonitoringMode.Reporting,
            SamplingInterval = -1,
            QueueSize = 100,
            CacheQueueSize = 100,
            Filter = filter 
        };
        // Log("Step 5 - Add a list of items you wish to monitor to the subscription.");
        var list = new List<MonitoredItem> {
            triggeringItemId,
            /*
            monitoredItem,
            monitoredItem2
            */
        };

        list.ForEach(i => i.Notification += OnNotification);

        Debug.Log(list);

        subscription.AddItems(list);

        // Log("Step 6 - Add the subscription to the session.");
        session.AddSubscription(subscription);
        subscription.Create();
```

Comment: Hey I know it's been a while since this was posted. But where you able to retrieve the event information using that OnNotification method with the monitored Item having an EventNotifier as an attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding some 'Select' clauses to the EventFilter. The following list corresponds to the basic event type. The AlarmCondition types provide many more fields.

var filter = new EventFilter();

filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.EventId);
 filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType,  Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.EventType);
 filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.SourceNode);
 filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.SourceName);
 filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.Time);
 filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.ReceiveTime);
 filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.LocalTime);
 filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.Message);
 filter.AddSelectClause(ObjectTypes.BaseEventType, Opc.Ua.BrowseNames.Severity);

Answer (score 0):

In this order it works for me:

```
session.AddSubscription(subscription);
subscription.Create();
```

then I create `MonitoredItems` and then add them to subscription and the last step which you miss:

```
subscription.ApplyChanges();
```